# Cannot delete windows file in Python even after explicitly setting permission

Tags: python, windows, file, file-permissions, delete-file

I have a code which unzips an archived file into the temp directory of Windows. I store this unzipped temporary location and upon completion of my task, I try to delete it.

```
Class Check():
 def __init__(self, file_path, unzip_dir=None):
   self.file_path = file_path
   self.unzip_dir = unzip_dir


 def terminate(self):
   if self.unzip_dir is not None:
      unzipped_resources = os.path.join(self.unzip_dir, 'resources')
      os.chmod(unzipped_resources, stat.S_IWRITE |  stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR)
      shutil.rmtree(self.unzip_dir, ignore_errors=False)
```

I have no clue why it is throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\fakepath\Test\test.py", line 94, in tearDownClass
    CheckFile.obj.terminate()
  File "C:\fakepath\Test\test.py", line 58, in terminate
    shutil.rmtree(self.unzip_dir, ignore_errors=False)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 740, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 613, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 618, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 616, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmplphs09bi\\resources\\testfile.dll'
```

I have double-checked that the process using the `testfile.dll` is freeing the dll after using it. I can even delete the file manually by going to that location - so that tells me it is not being used by anyone anymore. I have tried explicitly setting the permission for the file, and the parent folder. What could possibly be causing this, and how can this be resolved?

It might be worth noting that this class object is being created and destroyed upon the beginning and ending of a unittest in python.

EDIT : I found out that the permission is not being set even by calling os.chmod explicitly and recursively on the entire tree. The permission before and after calling chmod remains the same, would be glad if someone helped to identify why.

Comment: You may need to `os.chmod` recursively?  Your `os.chmod` call only changed the permission of the top level directory, and not the specific path that had the permission error.

Comment: Hi @metatoaster, I have tried doing that too. os.chmod, surprisingly, is not changing the permission. I am pretty bummed, tbh. No matter how many times I call os.chmod, the permission before and after remains the same.

Comment: Did you also have the `.dll` being used in some way as part of a running program? If that's the case you might have to terminate that program.

Comment: No, I did not. The dll file is being used and released duly on time from the application being run. (I cross-verified logs to ensure it is). The issue comes after termination, when I attempt to clean up the directory. I checked the permission and the permission is not `0o777`.

Comment: There might be a delay with the release of the resource, or the resource was not actually released.  Try setting a debugger (could be as simple as wrapping that `rmtree` call in a try/except block and start the debugger with `import pdb;pdb.post_mortem()` and then verify the associated permission and program state. I would try to manually call `os.unlink` on the affected path again to rule out the timing issue, and failing that try to delete the file from outside the program (and verify the relevant permissions).